# why tinyMCE function not working on IE browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, tinymce

I am trying to validate the tinyMCE editor using Javascript. I have tested this on all browsers except IE. I don't know where the problem is in my code. Can anyone tell me where the problem is and how I can fix this issue?

##### Javascript

```
var description = tinyMCE.get('textid').getContent();

if(description ==  '')
{
    errors += 'Description must have some value!\n';
}
```

##### Html

```
 <textarea name="textid" id="textid" class="span6 autogrow"></textarea>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the Javascript code by using the F12 Developer Consoles on the browsers?